# Java String.contains: how to check an exactly string

Tags: java, string, contains

I'm using string.contains("string") to look for partitions in proc files. Line examples would be:

```
   8       0 sda 64154 32861 2927936 1462960 222942 512949 5776720 4355320 0 1029440 5818130
   8       1 sda1 29613 26082 1943594 1077290 23561 82884 851560 423330 0 235650 1500640
```

I have a string array. Each line is a element of the array. As some elements are not usefull, I check for the partitions name in the line. If a line has the name of one the existing partitions, it will be parsed.

That's why I cannot simple use string.equals; I can check if the line contains and then do some string manipulation with indexOf maybe, using then equals.

Thanks, sorry for not being clearer before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this as simple as you trying to check if two strings are equal, rather than a containment check? If so all you need is:

```
if (text1.equals(text2))
```

instead of

```
if (text1.contains(text2))
```

If that's *not* what you're after, you need to be clearer in your question.

EDIT (after the question update): It's still not *really* clear what you're trying to do. It sounds like you *may* be able to get away with:

```
if (line.contains(" sda "))
```

as this will *not* match `sda1`. Basically, take advantage of the fact that there's a space before and after the partition name, but there can't be one *in* the partition name.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code snippet below addresses your question. Basically, you can still use the equals function but use substring function also. In this case, I am starting with the 2nd character.

```
String str1 = "1234567890";
String str2 = "0234567890";

if ( str1.substring(1).equals( str2.substring(1) )) {
    System.out.format("String %s matches", str1);
}
```

Lastly, my message is to use all the functions available to do the job without writing your own code.

Have fun...